# How to transform a string to a specific format in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that reads in data from an RTC via `i2cdump`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TIME=$(i2cdump -r 0-6 -y 0 0x68 b)
TIME=${TIME:76:20}
echo $TIME
```

`OUTPUT: 16 44 17 03 15 11 22`

The output is in the form `SEC MIN HOUR DAY DATE MONTH YEAR`

I would like to now set my system time based on this output using `timedatectl` which requires the output be transformed

```
# timedatectl set-time 'YEAR-MONTH-DATE HOUR:MIN:SEC'
```

How can I transform a string of form `SEC MIN HOUR DAY DATE MONTH YEAR` to `'YEAR-MONTH-DATE HOUR:MIN:SEC'`?

I've tried replacing the spaces with colons for the time, but don't know how to properly format the date to be preceding the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably just passing the old format to read and then assemble from the variables is the cleanest way:

```
TIME="16 44 17 03 15 11 22"
read SEC MIN HOUR DAY DATE MONTH YEAR <<< "$TIME"
NEWTIME="20$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY $HOUR:$MIN:$SEC"
echo "$NEWTIME"
```

or more old fashion with piping into a while loop:

```
echo $TIME | while read SEC MIN HOUR DAY DATE MONTH YEAR; do
        NEWTIME="20$YEAR-$MONTH-$DATE $HOUR:$MIN:$SEC"
        echo "$NEWTIME"
done
```

Output:

```
2022-11-15 17:44:16
```

Of course `sed` and `awk`also works, though slightly less readable:

```
echo "16 44 17 03 15 11 22" | sed -e's/\([0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9][0-9]\)/20\7-\6-\5 \3:\2:\1/'
2022-11-15 17:44:16
echo "16 44 17 03 15 11 22" | awk '{print 20$7"-"$6"-"$5" "$3":"$2":"$1}'
2022-11-15 17:44:16
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! When I attempt to set the time I get an error. I just added `timedatectl set-time $NEWTIME` to the end of the script and it responds "Invalid number of arguments."

Comment: Put it inside the loop (before the `done`). The loop is only executed once but it is an easy way to deal with the fact that read opens a subshell.